# rails haml if add class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, haml

How can I write this code in haml without repeating the render line?

```
- if i % 2 == 0
  %section.wrapper-md.list
    = render partial: 'property'
- else
  %section.wrapper-md.list.background-gray
    = render partial: 'property'
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
%section.wrapper-md.list{class: ('background-gray' if i.even?)}
  = render partial: 'property'
```

Also you could try using the [`cycle`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-cycle) helper and no need for counters

```
%section.wrapper-md.list{class: cycle('', 'background-gray')}
  = render partial: 'property'
```

Comment: I have to wait 10 minutes for that, I'm waiting

Comment: hmm, I didn't know that, wonder what kind of rule that is, I'll look around, thanks

Comment: ruby/rails has so many convenience methods it's hard to remember them all